# Can not start GG node (rev 6) in Windows 7 (works fine for rev 5.3.3)

Tags: gridgain

C:...\GitHub\gridgain>bin\ggstart.bat
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gridgain.grid.startup.cmdline.GridC
ommandLineTransformer
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gridgain.grid.startup.cmdline.GridC
ommandLineRandomNumberGenerator
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gridgain.grid.util.portscanner.Grid
JmxPortFinder
bin\ggstart.bat, WARN: Failed to resolve JMX host. JMX will be disabled.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gridgain.grid.startup.cmdline.GridC
ommandLineStartup

Comment: It is NOT that obvious case: "GRIDGAIN_HOME is pointing to the wrong location"

I did try Hyper-v to emulate "windows 7 fresh box" and rev 6 does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors usually happen when GRIDGAIN_HOME is pointing to the wrong location. Given that v5.3.3 starts successfully, I suspect GRIDGAIN_HOME still points to it.

UPD: After reading your solution I think I understood what the original problem was. GitHub download link (download ZIP button) does NOT contain GridGain release, it contains only source code from which you can build GridGain jar. You should run maven build procedure to get gridgain.jar in work folder.

If you do not want to build jar from sources, you can download latest release package [here](http://www.gridgain.org/download/).

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer

Windows user should use the following link to download GG
http://www.gridgain.com/media/gridgain-platform-ent-6.0.2win.zip

NOT the one from the github!!!